# NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_CONFIG_CLASS on Citrus Simulator WS project

Tags: spring-boot, citrus-framework

I'm getting this exception when running a fresh generated project using the Maven archetype org.citrusframework.archetypes:citrus-simulator-archetype-ws (Archetype for Citrus SOAP simulator).

I tried whit both 2.1.1 and 2.1.0 versions with the same result:

> 2022-07-07 10:19:40.718  WARN 3113 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.consol.citrus.config.CitrusSpringConfig]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_CONFIG_CLASS

> 2022-07-07 10:19:40.734  INFO 3113 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.

> 2022-07-07 10:19:40.829 ERROR 3113 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.consol.citrus.config.CitrusSpringConfig]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_CONFIG_CLASS
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:610) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]

I tried to find mixed versions of the spring jars in the dependencies tree with no success. This is the generated pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example.simulator</groupId>
  <artifactId>ws-simulator</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Citrus SOAP Simulator</name>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <citrus.version>3.1.0</citrus.version>
    <citrus.simulator.version>2.1.1</citrus.simulator.version>
    <spring.boot.version>2.5.4</spring.boot.version>
    <testng.version>7.3.0</testng.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Citrus Simulator -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.citrusframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>citrus-simulator-starter</artifactId>
      <version>${citrus.simulator.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.citrusframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>citrus-simulator-ui</artifactId>
      <version>${citrus.simulator.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Citrus -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.consol.citrus</groupId>
      <artifactId>citrus-ws</artifactId>
      <version>${citrus.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>${testng.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
          <source>${java.version}</source>
          <target>${java.version}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>integration-tests</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>repackage</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                      <classifier>executable</classifier>
                  </configuration>
              </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>pre-integration-test</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <fork>true</fork>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>post-integration-test</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

I tried using java 17 at first and switched to java 11 which is the target version in the pom, but nothing changed.

Any ideas where may be the conflict?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to upgrade the citrus dependencies. (Upgrade Citurs Version to 3.2.1)

See as reference https://github.com/Malyky/citrusSoapSimulator

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).